# Why is it that if P(a|b,c)=P(b|a,c), then P(a|c) = P(b|c) is not true

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given that a,b,c are random variables and 
$$P(a|b,c) = P(b|a,c)$$
we can rewrite it as
$$\frac{P(a,b,c)}{P(b,c)} = \frac{P(a,b,c)}{P(a,c)}$$
Then $P(b,c) = P(a,c)$. And we have
$$P(a|c) = \frac{P(a,c)}{P(c)}$$
$$P(b|c) = \frac{P(b,c)}{P(c)}$$
Since $P(b,c) = P(a,c)$, $P(a|c) = P(b|c)$.

However, apparently this is a false statement even though the math seems to work out fine. Can anyone point out what mistake i made in my reasoning?

Comment: Note that you are making the following assumptions in your math: $P(a, c) > 0$, $P(b, c) > 0$, and $P(c) > 0$.

Comment: Note that we don't usually condition on a random variable, but on an event, such as a random variable taking a certain value or landing in a certain set of values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement is true, depending on the exact interpretation of $P(a|b,c)=P(b|a,c)$. There are situations when this statement cannot hold for all possible values of $a,b,c$.

For example if $a,b,c$ are the results of the first, second and first coin toss, i.e. $a=c$ then issues can arise, e.g.:

$$1/4=P(b=H,c=T)\neq P(a=H,c=T)=0.$$

Conditioning implicitly assumes the conditioning is done on an event with positive probability. Notice that this would also give:

$$0=P(a=H|b=H,c=T)\neq P(b=H|a=C,b=H)=\mbox{undefined}$$